# Find first occurence of substring before a certain position

Tags: php, strpos

In PHP, if I have a long string, IE 10'000 chars, how would you suggest I go about finding the first occurence of a certain string before and after a given position.

IE, if I have the string:

```
BaaaaBcccccHELLOcccccBaaaaB
```

I can use strpos to find the position of HELLO. How could I then go about finding the position of the first occurence of B before HELLO and the first occurence of B after HELLO?

Answer (score 1):

You can use stripos() and strripos() to find the first occurrence of a sub-string inside a string. You can also supply a negative offset to strripos() function to search in reverse order (from right to left). [strripos() with negative offset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php)

```
$body = "BaaaaBcccccHELLOcccccBaaaaB";
$indexOfHello = stripos($body, 'Hello');
if ($indexOfHello !== FALSE)
{
    // First Occurrence of B before Hello
    $indexOfB= stripos(substr($body,0,$indexOfHello),'B',($indexOfHello * -1));
    print("First Occurance of B before Hello is ".$indexOfB."\n") ;
    
    // First Occurrence of B before Hello (in reverse order)
    $indexOfB= strripos($body,'B',($indexOfHello * -1));
    print("First Occurrence of B before Hello (in reverse order) is ".$indexOfB."\n") ;
    
    // First Occurrence of B after Hello
    $indexOfB= stripos($body,'B',$indexOfHello);
    print("First Occurance of B after Hello is ".$indexOfB."\n") ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you think about optimization there a lot of [pattern search algorithms](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/algorithms-gq/pattern-searching/)

Here is sample of naive pattern search:

```
/**
 * Naive algorithm for Pattern Searching
*/
function search(string $pat, string $txt, int $searchFrom = 0, ?int $searchTill = null) 
{ 
    $M = strlen($pat); 
    $N = strlen($txt); 

    if ($searchTill !== null && $searchTill < $N){
        $N = $searchTill;
    }

    for ($i = $searchFrom; $i <= $N - $M; $i++) 
    { 
  
        // For current index i,  
        // check for pattern match  
        for ($j = 0; $j < $M; $j++) 
            if ($txt[$i + $j] != $pat[$j]) 
                break; 
  
        // if pat[0...M-1] =  
        // txt[i, i+1, ...i+M-1] 
        if ($j == $M)  
            return $i;
    } 
} 

// Driver Code 
$txt = "BaaaaBcccccHELLOcccccBaaaaB"; 
if (null!==($helloPos = search("HELLO", $txt))){

    print("First Occurance of B before Hello is ".search("B", $txt, 0, $helloPos)."<br>") ;
    print("First Occurance of B after Hello is ".search("B", $txt, $helloPos, null)."<br>") ;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Given the position…

To find the first occurrence before, you can take the `substr()` before the match and use `strrpos()`.

To find the first occurrence after, you can still use `strpos()` and set the *offset* parameter.

Comment: But for the first occurrence before, if I take the substr before the match (ie: substr between 0 and POSITION_OF_HELLO) then how can I guarantee he will return the last match in that substr (the last match in that substr will be the match just before HELLO). If we look at the string I gave in example, the substr would be BaaaaBccccc, but strpos will return the first B.

Comment: This is not a solution. Everyone knows such functions.